# How to add pins to map?

Tags: c#, xamarin, location, maps

So I am creating an app which will have map with pre added locations (pins) into it and when user comes near that location (s)he will get notification. My  problem is, how to add Pins into Xamarin Maps? I am not using Google Maps, I am trying to do with "Xamarin Custom Map?".

I have opened map, but it is opening in Google Maps appliation. I looked for a way not to use Google Maps Api, but I didn't find a single solution how to do this without Google Maps, so is it even possible?

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;

var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);

Map.OpenAsync(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
```

This code here opens map application on my smartphone (in this case GoogleMaps), so I am wondering is it possible to add pins to it, or somehow open map inside of my app wihtout using Google Maps API?

Comment: you need to add a map control to your app, not call the external map app.  Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map

Comment: Hey, thx for answer, but here in docs there is usage of Google Maps API key, I don't have a key and I am wondering is it possible to do it without Google Maps API key?

Comment: Not on Android.  Is there a reason you can't get an API Key?

Comment: Well, can I get it for free or it requires fee?

Comment: Is it even possible add map in your app if you are not using Google Maps API?

Comment: Use a map that doesn't depend on the Google API.  Or just get a free Google API key.  It takes 5 minutes to do.

Comment: What map would that be?
But what are limiations of free Google API key? How many users can use it?

Comment: SO is not a free research service.  You can easily search for these answers yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx all for feedback, using Google Maps API is easiest and best solution for this! :-)